# I need a RegExp which accepts only accepts slashes in text box?

Tags: javascript

I need a RegExp  which accepts only accepts slashes in text box but not remaining,
The formate is YYYY/MM/DD

Example : my text box is accepting "2015/@/25, 2015/12/$" inside the date text field as like this above mentioned , but it need to accept only date specified formate only "2015/12/25" and I need to accept

4 -YYYY
2 -MM
2 -DD
2 -Slashes(YYYY/MM/DD).

Answer (score 0):

A valid RegExp could be:
(If you provide a little piece of your code we could help more)

```
var reg = /^(\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})$/;
```

Four digits + a slash + two digits + a slash + two digits